# How to use two events in an "always" block in verilog

Tags: verilog

I have two push buttons (using  Basys2 rev C board) and I want to increment a register (counter) when I push one of them. I used this:

```
always @( posedge pb1 or posedge pb2 )
 begin
 if(count2==9) count2=0;
 else count2= count2+1;
 end
```

but when I implemented it (using ISE 9.2), an error appeared:

> The logic for  does not match a known FF or Latch template.

However when I tried it using just one event (`posedge pb1`), it worked.

So why did that happen?

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that the target technology (I am guessing in your case is an FPGA or CPLD) doesn't have the physical circuit required to implement the functionality you described with this behavioural code.

One of the important things to consider when writing synthesizable RTL (verilog or VHDL) is you are describing an electronic circuit. You should understand what real world logic you are trying implement (combinatorial logic, registers) before you start coding. In this case, you are describing a register with two separate clocks--something that doesn't exist in any FPGA or ASIC library I've seen. If you can't figure out what you're trying to implement, the chances are the synthesizer can't either.

In other words, not everything you can describe in Verilog can be translated into an actual circuit.

The solution depends on what you want to do - if you *require* that the counter increments on both `pb1` and `pb2` rising edges, *irrespective of the other `pb`s state*, I would look into solutions which use another (independent) clock (`clk` in the code below) - something like this:

```
reg old_pb1, old_pb2;
always @ (posedge clk) begin
  if (old_pb1 == 0 && pb1 == 1)
    if(count2==9) count2 = 0;
    else count2 <= count2 + 1;
  if (old_pb2 == 0 && pb2 == 1)
    if(count2==9) count2 = 0;
    else count2 <= count2 + 1;
  old_pb1 <= pb1;
  old_pb2 <= pb2;
end
```

If you have no other clock, you could also combine both input signals like in this example:

```
wire pbs = pb1 | pb2;
always @ (pbs) begin
 if(count2==9) count2 <= 0;
 else count2 <= count2 + 1;
end
```

Another option would be to use independent counters for the inputs:

```
always @ (posedge pb1)
 begin
   if(count_pb1==9) count_pb1 <= 0;
   else count_pb1 <= count_pb1 + 1;
 end
always @ (posedge pb2)
 begin
   if(count_pb2==9) count_pb2 <= 0;
   else count_pb2 <= count_pb2 + 1;
 end

wire [4:0] count2 = count_pb1 + count_pb2;
```

All options have their own restrictions, limitations and drawbacks, therefore it depends heavily on what you want to do. Corner cases matter.

Note that I put these example codes together without testing them - please let me know in a comment if you are having trouble with any of them and I look into it.

Comment: A few things I would like to note on this answer (the first explanation is good so I dont want to answer again). Firstly, any clocked block (for example `always @(posedge clk)`) should use NBA (`<=`) not Blocking (`=`) assignment (and never mix the two). Secondly, I would shine away from asynchronous solutions like you have as examples 2 and 3, as FPGAs are really designed to use push button inputs as clocks. Its better to get in the habit of the global clock, especially for tasks as the op proposed.

Comment: One of the important things to consider when writing synthesizable RTL (verilog or VHDL) is you are describing an electronic circuit. You should understand what real world logic you are trying implement (combinatorial logic, registers) before you start coding. In this case, you are describing a register with two separate clocks--something that doesn't exist in any FPGA or ASIC library I've seen. If you can't figure out what you're trying to implement, the chances are the synthesizer can't either.

Comment: Also, you really should debounce the push button inputs, otherwise your count will most likely go up by a random number rather than by 1 each time you push a button.

Comment: Thanks @BarryMoss for the expansion of my first two paragraphs. Would you mind if I add this to my answer? I think it would add some real value to it. Also, I am aware of the debouncing problem... but felt that this was a bit off-topic with respect to OP's question. Also I'd avoid going down that rabbit hole as the relationship between clock frequency as well as type and quality of the bushbutton becomes important... I think this should be a separate question.

Comment: @Unn, thanks for your feedback. Although I agree with you in general, in some cases using blocking assignments within clocked blocks can be useful - and as Barry said, as long as you understand what it will turn into through synthesis, should be fine IMO. But as with the debouncing problem, I think this goes beyond the original question and should be addressed separately - maybe I'll add some links to other questions on these subjects.

Comment: @FriendFX However, it really does matter between blocking and NBA. In the cases you have above, the `count` variables are all suppose to be registers storing the value of the current count. Thus, they should behave as registers. However, if you use blocking assignment, the new value of `count` may or may not be used in other logic depending on execution order of the blocks when the correct behavior is to only use the old value. Now, synthesis tools might frequently figure out what you are trying to say, but having code that doesnt simulate correctly is never good.

Comment: See this doc for guidelines on good style that will always simulate and synthesize well: http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA_rev1_2.pdf

Comment: @Unn I am aware of the differences and dangers in using blocking assignments. In the examples 2 and 3 I have given however, there is no difference. And in some cases - e.g. having a specific variable which is assigned to in a single clocked `always` block - using NBA can save quite a bit of confusion (and typing) in certain cases. I agree with you, one has to be careful - but I still think this isn't relevant to the question given by the OP.

Comment: @Unn To give better guidelines for beginners, I have changed the assignments anyway... it is probably safer to keep it like that. Thanks for the link by the way, it is a good guide. +1

Comment: @FriendFX -- feel free to add my comments into your answer.  While I agree that the comment on debouncing is out of the scope of the original question, I could see it becoming an issue for the OP as soon as he made this fix. :)

Comment: Thanks @BarryMoss - yes, it probably will be :-) ...the OP might also run into other problems, but I thought one step at a time :-)